# Why can't I access my controller's functions inside directive html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to call a function defined in my controller from within the markup of a third-party directive. The strange thing is that I can access regular variables just fine, but functions don't appear to show up at all.

Part of my controller:

```
$scope.map = {
            control: {},
            center: {
                latitude: 45,
                longitude: -73
            },
            zoom: 8,
            currentMarker:{id:-1, coords: {latitude: 45, longitude: -73}},
            wndoptions:{
              boxClass: 'bubble'
            }            
        };

        [...]

$scope.moveMarkerUp = function(){
          alert('Do things here');
       };
```

And the markup:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <input type="button" value="U" ng-click="moveMarkerUp()" ng-show="showWnd"></input>
    <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" ng-show="true" draggable="true" control="map.control">
         <window coords="map.currentMarker.coords" show="showWnd" options="map.wndoptions">
                <div >
                    Marker {{showWnd}}
                    <input type="button" value="Up" ng-click="moveMarkerUp()" ng-show="{{showWnd}}"></input>
                </div>
         </window>
         <markers models="markers" coords="'coords'" click="'clk'"></markers>
    </google-map>
</div>
```

So the function fires as expected when the first button is pressed, but nothing happens for  the second one, inside the window tag, but when I evaluate the variables like `map` or `showWnd` here, they do display the correct values. I've even tried setting a function inside the map object, but when it is printed out this way, the function variable isn't even listed in the object.

Comment: In angular we have child scope and parent scope concept.guess google-map directive has child scope so you can't able to call parent controller function.better put the button outside of the directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window` directive creates a child scope and your function exists on the parent.  Try referencing like this `ng-click="$parent.moveMarkerUp()"`.